# Swagger - misleading sample value for date-time field, how can I fix this?

Tags: java, swagger

In Swagger model / Example value, I see this sample value for a `$date-time` field.

`"lastModifiedDate": "2020-07-09T12:50:48.461Z"`

[image: pic1]

But I have defined this field like this

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", timezone="America/New_York")
private Date lastModifiedDate;
```

So the actual values returned by my API look like this:

```
"lastModifiedDate": "2020-07-09T07:44:35.366-04:00"
```

So I am not sure why swagger is not detecting this.

Probably because this `JsonFormat` is a `Jackson` annotation.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat
```

So... do I need to add some additional Swagger annotation here?
I don't have a Swagger descriptor file (or don't have control over it),
I have just annotations in the Java code.

Can this be done via annotations?

Answer (score -2):

I think that the annotation required for documenting your moddel is @ApiModelProperty, take a look on it http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiModel.html
hope it will be helpfull.

Comment: Thanks but these are more general, they don't allow me to specify date/time pattern.